# hide the keyboard if action sheet is going to popup

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios4

I have an app in which i have 2 textfield. Now my problem is, Let say first user taps on normal textfield. Which will popups keyboard. Then without selecting done button he taps on date field. Which will popup action sheet (without dismissing the keyboard). After hiding actionsheet user has to tap on other text filed and click on return key of the keyboard.

I want to hide the keyboard if action sheet is going to popup?

my code is below

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{


    if([textField isEqual:txtdob])
    {

        [textField resignFirstResponder];


        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
       // txtdob.inputView=actionSheet;
        CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

        datepicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
        datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        //[datepicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
        [datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDateInLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [actionSheet addSubview:datepicker];
        [datepicker release];

        UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
        closeButton.momentary = YES; 
        closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
        closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
        closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
        [closeButton release];

        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

        [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this in your ViewController

```
[self.view endEditing:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol method `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`? The method is called whenever a UITextField goes out of focus, like when, for example, the user taps another element in the view.

Try putting this in your delegate class:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Also, make sure the textfields' delegate is set to a class that implements this above method. Hope this helps!